# That Brownian Motion's increments are gaussian is "not surprising"?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion, probability-limit-theorems

In section 1 of chapter 1 of [*Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Continuous_Martingales_and_Brownian_Moti.html?id=1ml95FLM5koC), the authors claim that

> the fact that the increments of of Brownian motion are gaussian random
>   variables "is not surprising in view of the central-limit theorem".

Why do they put a hyphen between 'central' and 'limit'? Just kidding, my real question is: **What do they mean by this?**

My understanding of the CLT is limited to, "the averages of same-size samples from any distribution converges in distribution to a gaussian distribution" (and please correct me if that's wrong), but I don't see how that applies here.

Comment: "Not surprising" doesn't mean "easily proven from." I think all they're saying is that Brownian motion is a lot like adding up a lot of random variables, so, well, it isn't surprising. A lot of times, we'd expect something to be true, by analogy. In those cases, it isn't surprising if it is true, only if it is not. :)

Comment: This is a way of recalling that, since Brownian motion is the limit of renormalized random walks, the appearance of CLT, hence of centered gaussian distributions, is natural in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "the averages of same-size samples from any distribution converges in distribution to a gaussian distribution" (...) don't see how that applies here.

It applies if you treat the increment from $B(0)$ to $B(t)$ as a sum of $n$ independent identically distributed increments $B(t_{i})-B(t_{i-1})$, where $t_i =  \frac{i}{n} t$.  Just divide the time interval into $n$ equal pieces and take the limit of large $n$.

Just as non-surprisingly, the same argument applies to time-changed Brownian motion $B(f(t))$. The subintervals should be equal in variance of the increments, instead of time.

Answer (score 2):

The context is the "real" Brownian Motion, the one with the pollen and water particules.

A "2D-increment" in the trayectory of the pollen is the result of a very large number of identically distributed and independent shocks. Then, by the CLT (under finite variance hypothesis) the sum of the shocks will be asymptotically normal.